# Why not use alternate elements as vertical search nodes in Skip Lists?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, skip-lists

In most implementations of skip lists I've seen, they use a randomized algorithm to decide if an element must be copied into the upper level.

But I think using odd indexed elements at each level to have copies in the upper level will give us logarithmic search complexity. Why isn't this used?

E.g. :
Data : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Skip List:

1--------------------

1--------------------9

1--------5----------9

1----3---5----7----9

1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9

Comment: You're right that the depth would be logarithmic. But: If you inserted an element at position `0`, all items at previously odd positions would then be at even positions. How would you handle this in your solution?

Comment: There is a data structure that does something similar:  the deterministic skip list. It has a deterministic rule for what level a new node should be but it's more complicated than what you suggest. It is in some sense equivalent to a particular brand of self-balancing tree. Google it for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not used because it is easy to maintain while building the list from scratch - but what happens when you add/remove element to an existing list? Elements that used to be odd indexed are even indexed now, and vise versa.

In your example, assume you now add 3.5, all to maintain the DS as you described, it will require `O(k + k/2 + k/4 +  ... )`  changes to the DS, where `k` is the number of elements AFTER the element you have just inserted.

This basically gives you `O(n/2 + n/4 + ...) = O(n)` add/remove complexity on average.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you start deleting nodes or inserting nodes in the middle the structure quickly requires rebalancing or it loses its logarithmic guarantees on access and update.

Actually there is a structure very similar to what you suggest, an interval tree, which gets around the update problem by not using actual elements as intermediate node labels. It can also require some care to get good performance.